# What does raster$fun do?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, mosaic

I am trying to use the code referenced in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109774/r-raster-mosaic-from-list-of-rasters) but I can't figure out why it is necessary to run `raster.list$fun = mean`. (See answers in link) Can anyone tell me what this does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `do.call()` you have to supply your arguments as a **list**:

In the provided link the do.call function is used to mosaic a list of raster images. So the first argument of the function do.call() is always the function you want to use (in this case `mosaic`), and the sencond argument would be a list of additional parameters. In this case the raster images plus a function that should be used for overlapping areas during the mosaicing (here mean).

So by typing `raster.list$fun = mean` you just add a new element called "fun" to the list, that contains the r-base function `mean()`. This will then be used as an input for the mosaic function invoked by do.call.

For more information please look up the help pages for `?do.call` and `?mosaic`. Hope this helps.