# what does ""fun" is missing" error mean from mosaic() in [r] raster package?

Tags: r, raster, r-mosaic

I am trying to mosaic a (subset of a) list of rasters in [r] using mosaic() from the raster package.

I am basing my code on posts such as:

[R: Raster mosaic from list of rasters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109774/r-raster-mosaic-from-list-of-rasters)

I have tried both of these methods below,

```
allrasters_m$fun<-mean
allrasters_dnbr_mosaic<-do.call("mosaic",allrasters_m[grep("_dnbr",allrasters_m)])
```

```
allrasters_dnbr<-allrasters_m[grep("_dnbr",allrasters_m)]
allrasters_dnbr_mosaic<-do.call(mosaic,allrasters_dnbr)
```

and both give me this error message:

Error in .makeTextFun(fun) : argument "fun" is missing, with no default

any ideas?  Thanks!

Here is some preceding code if that helps:

```
rastlist_m <- list.files(path=path, pattern='tif$', full.names=TRUE)

allrasters_m <- lapply(rastlist_m, raster)
```

Comment: You need to specify the function to use in overlapping areas, for example, mean, min or max. Something like: `mosaic(...., fun = mean)`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `allrasters_m$fun<-mean` statement I had run prior to the first line of code in this post.     I have also tried two other ways 1) `allrasters_dnbr_mosaic<-do.call(mosaic,allrasters_m[grep("_dnbr",allrasters_m)], fun=mean)`  and 2)   `allrasters_dnbr_mosaic<-do.call(mosaic,allrasters_dnbr, fun=mean)`   and both give me the error message "Error in do.call(mosaic, allrasters_m[grep("_dnbr", allrasters_m)],  : unused argument (fun = mean)"

Comment: Note - I have intentionally masked these rasters so that there is no overlap, i.e. they look like spots on a giraffe.

Comment: I wonder if mosaic(), even with fun=mean never worked because there is no overlapping area in the rasters I am mosaicking, that would explain the error message 'unused argument(fun=mean)'.  Merge() was able to handle combining multiple rasters that have no overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why, but 'merge' with the exact same syntax worked.  `allrasters_dnbr_mosaic<-do.call(merge,allrasters_m[grep("_dnbr",allrasters_m)])` 
so this is technically solved, but I don't understand why merge worked and mosaic didn't.